# Is Lync 2013 Server SDK compatible with SfB Server 2015?

Tags: skype-for-business, skypedeveloper

We have made an application which uses the Lync 2013 Server SDK to monitor interactions.

The IT department asked me if they can allow an upgrade to Skype for Business Server 2015. There doesn't seem to be a Server SDK for SfB 2015.

Will my application which uses Lync 2013 Server SDK still work?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/skype/skypedeveloperplatform

Take a look at the table at the end of the topic.

Answer (score 2):

It should do, our application i built against one version of the SDK and runs against all versions 2010, 2013, and 2015.